# Why can't I create more than one instance of my class?

Tags: python, class, object

When I create the first instance of my class it runs perfectly. But when I try to create a second instance I get a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

```
class Settlement:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name()
    .
    .
    .
    First_Name = [list items here]
    Second_Name = [list items here]
    .
    .
    .
    def name(self):
        first = Settlement.First_Name[random.randint(0, (len(Settlement.First_Name)-1))]
        second = Settlement.Second_Name[random.randint(0, (len(Settlement.Second_Name)-1))]
        Settlement.name = "Name: "+ first+second


MySettlement = Settlement()
MySettlement2 = Settlement()
```

Comment: Can you 1) fix your indentation and 2) show where you actually create an instance of your class? Also note - you're not using any instance level attributes so instances will be sharing the class level ones anyway...

Comment: This is an aside but you should use `random.choice` here instead of `random.int`

Comment: I addressed 1 and 2, but I'm not sure I understand that last part, it sounds like it might be the cause of my problem though...

Comment: There is no code in between the two calls to `Settlement()`?

Comment: @user3650751 it's not the cause of the error you're receiving but it's definitely another problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 1: The problem is that you are using name as function and as Class variable. Change the Settlement.name to something else and it work.

```
import random
class Settlement:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name()

    First_Name = ['Romaan', 'test']
    Second_Name = ['Shmrd', 'test']

    def name(self):
        first = Settlement.First_Name[random.randint(0, (len(Settlement.First_Name)-1))]
        second = Settlement.Second_Name[random.randint(0, (len(Settlement.Second_Name)-1))]
        Settlement.nameeee = "Name: "+ first+second


MySettlement = Settlement()
MySettlement2 = Settlement()
```

Update 2:
Just to ensure you avoid such mistakes of using the same name as function name, you can declare all the class on Top and/or instance variables in **init** function

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
def name(self):
    first = Settlement.First_Name[random.randint(0, (len(Settlement.First_Name)-1))]
    second = Settlement.Second_Name[random.randint(0, (len(Settlement.Second_Name)-1))]
    Settlement.name = "Name: "+ first+second
```

You have a method called `name` - when you call name - it finishes with `Settlement.name = ...` - this effectively rebinds `Settlement.name` to be a string (eg: it's no longer your `name` method and callable) hence the error you're receiving.

You need to use a separate name for the attribute and the method. I'd probably call `name` `create_name`...

The other issue is that you want to use `self.name =` instead of `Settlement.name =` otherwise you're re-using the same name across all instances.